# Can I write comments in TSQL files that won't end up being published?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using a code generator of my own to produce T-SQL code, using some criterias. I want the output code to show what criterias were used to produce the code, but I'd like to keep that information from being deployed to the server.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE PROC blabla
AS
BEGIN

    /*
    This code is the result of calling code generator X with the following criterias:

    Variable1 = 'My first variable value'
    Variable2 = 'My second variable value'
    */

    (Actual T-SQL code)

END
```

Basically, I want to know if a special syntax exists inside SSDT to delimit a non compilable text segment. **Not looking for pure TSQL syntax here!**

Does it exists?

An additional note: I'm aware that I can use TSQL comment removal tools but I'm looking for a more proactive solution here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can keep the comments outside of the stored procedures and separate it from `create procedure` with `GO`:

```
/* A comment about the criteria used...*/
go
create procedure a
as
begin
  declare @i int
end
go
```

This way the stored procedure will not include your comments, as it would be created in a separate batch.

Comment: It works! I first tried without using the `GO` statement (just putting comments above the `CREATE` statement). It didn't work, the comment still was part of the published script. So `GO` *did* make the difference, indeed.

Comment: This is correct, any comment preceding the `create procedure` in the same batch is considered a part of the SP. And this creates a risk, that these comments may be omitted unintentionally in the future, this is why I always recommend putting the descriptive comments between `as` and `begin` to make them a part of the SP body and preserve from any accidental truncation.